# SQL: grouping tables with many-to-many relations

Tags: sql, ms-access, many-to-many, grouping

I have the following tables:

```
User: id
Table1: id, user_id, 
Table2: id, date_
```

(Table2 relates to Table1 as many-to-one,  Table1 relates to User as many-to-one, it works as many-to-many relations between Table2 and User, but Table1 carries additional information(not relevant to this problem))

I need a query looks like:

```
row: User.id  Table1.id  Table2.id  Table2.date_
```

Where for every user is shown only one row where Table2.date_ is max from all Table2 related to that user

Thanks in advance,
Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (note, I omitted Table2.ID, as it is the same as Table1.ID):

```
SELECT Table1.user_id, Table1.ID, q.max_date
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ID, MAX(date_) as max_date FROM Table2 GROUP BY ID) AS q
ON Table1.ID = q.ID
```